# How to use promise inisde forEach to check if forEach is completed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, promise

This is the first time I am trying to use promises. When `forEach` is done, I want to call another function for further processing, with `forEach`, it's only printing one time `insertIDBEvents`, the next call it does not print.

What is the correct way to use a promise for `forEach`?

nodeCtrl.js

```
    var ctr = 0;
    var insertIDBEvents = [];
    data.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        event = JSON.parse(element.variables.event.value);
        if (typeof element.variables.caseIdFound !== 'undefined') {
            //asynchronous(function(data){
            Promise.all(array)
                .then(function(element) {
                    ctr++;
                    console.log("caseIdFound boolean", element.variables.caseIdFound.value);
                    insertIDBEvents.push(element);
                    console.log(insertIDBEvents);
                    if (ctr === array.length) {
                        console.log('IDBinsert', JSON.stringify(insertIDBEvents));
                    anotherFunction(insertIDBEvents)
                    }
                })

        }

    });

anotherIDBEvents (data) {
   // do something with data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to use `Promise.all` with an iteration is to map your array of elements into an array of promises that perform the necessary async operation relative to those elements and then pass that array of promises into `Promise.all`.

So here's a general idea:

```
Promise.all(
  arrayOfElements.map(
    element => (
      functionThatReturnsAPromise(element)
    )
  )  
)
.then(results => {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: i wanted to apply Promise only inside if condition and that array is still being processed by forEach

Comment: @hussain doesn't work that way, you can't mix sync and async code that way.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange your code so the `Promise.all` is on the outside. Also, the values of your array need to be Promises.

It's a little hard to tell, since the code above obviously doesn't work, but I think you'll want to map your data array to have each element run a promise, then dump all of that into a `Promise.all`.

Something like this:

```
var ctr = 0;
var insertIDBEvents = [];

Promise.all(data.map(element => {
  event = JSON.parse(element.variables.event.value);

  if (typeof element.variables.caseIdFound !== 'undefined') { 
    ctr++;
    console.log("caseIdFound boolean", element.variables.caseIdFound.value);
    insertIDBEvents.push(element);
    console.log(insertIDBEvents);
    if (ctr === array.length) {
      console.log('IDBinsert', JSON.stringify(insertIDBEvents));
      anotherFunction(insertIDBEvents)
    }
  }
})).then(() => {
  anotherIDBEvents(data);
});
```

Comment: some events has `element.variables.caseIdFound` undefined values i dont want to push those events to anotherFunction, so my concern was only push events that has value to anotherFunction, rest of events will be processed in Promise.all with some other logic

Comment: @hussain You can add something like `.filter()` to filter out the data before calling the map function.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to build your array of promises first, filtering with conditionals, then pass the array to `Promise.all()`, or another common approach is building an array of elements and using `Promise.map()` (if the lib you are using supports it), to execute the same code for each iteration instead of instantiating identical promises for each element.

```
const anotherFunction = element => {
  // do something with data
  return element
}

const elements = data.map(element => {
  return !!element.variables.caseIdFound
})

Promise.map(elements, element => {
  return anotherFunction(element)
}).then(res => {
  //handle resolution
}).catch(err => {
  //handle exceptions
})
```